# How to pass data to google charts from sqlite3 database on ROR web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I am a beginner ROR web developer, I have google charts running on my web app . But charts are drawn based on the data hard coded.

my code:

Gchart.line(:data => [300, 100, 30, 200, 100, 200, 300, 10], :axis_with_labels =>'x',
            :axis_labels => ['Jan|July|Jan|July|Jan'])

I need the chart to be drawn based on the data drawn from my database (Sqlite3). 
Can I do it with googlecharts ? If yes, how do I write code to draw data from db.

Comment: The above is kind of difficult for this application. I'm working on this problem right now and will post updates if I find them and remember to: check out this other question for some more food for thought http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272454/rails-how-to-pass-values-from-an-array-to-the-google-chart-script Wow I think I hit the jackpot ==>
http://zargony.com/2012/02/29/google-charts-on-your-site-the-unobtrusive-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely, you can do it. Google Chart API is a JavaScript library, so it just some data to pass in. If you are using Rails 3.2, the common way to do is to render the data within the html `dom` with `data` attribute, then use `jQuery` to access the data.

You can read more about this from railscast episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: thanks for replying, how to render data within html with dom and data attribute. Sorry I am a newbie.